# cant truncate tables with a pk/ fk relationship?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table called Folder with 3 fields: Id (PK), Name, UserId (FK)

and another table called User with two fields: Id (PK), UserName

i am trying to run this sql:

```
truncate table Folder
truncate table User
```

i get the following error

```
Cannot truncate table 'Folder' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
Cannot truncate table 'user'   because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
```

...even after deleting all the records in both tables i get this. why am i not allowed to truncate my tables?

how can i reset the seeds of the PK's easily without using truncate if there is now way to run a truncate on pk/fk relationship tables?

Edit: 
DB diagram added
[image]

Comment: It looks like `Folder` is also being used as an FK in another table. That table would need to be dumped first?

Comment: all the tables in the DB have no records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reseed, use [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table', RESEED, 1)
```

Or you'd have to drop the FK, truncate, then recreate the FK.

This is by design: TRUNCATE TABLE is simple page deallocation and constraints are not checked row by row. This limitation means you can't truncate when there are FKs.. even if you disable the FK.

Comment: thanks, but i dont see why i cant truncate tables. i am sure this is possible even with constraints being used.

Comment: I just told you why: there are foreign keys on the table. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx